# What is the output of a signal in time domain that passed through a High Pass Filter with simple transfer function

Tags: control-theory, transfer-function, signal-processing, optimal-control, electronic-filters

If a signal function $ U(t) =  25 – (5 – t)^2$ is passed through a high pass filter with transfer function $\frac{s}{s + ω}$. what is the output signal Y(t). I know that the transfer function $H(s) = \frac{Y(s)}{U(s)}$. If I understand the basic concept, I can solve my own problems. I will also appreciate it if someone can reference a textbook.

Comment: Look for a basic signal processing book like this one https://www.amazon.com/Digital-Signal-Processing-John-Proakis/dp/0131873741

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is

1. use Laplace transform to $U(t)$ so you would get $\mathcal{L}(U(t))=U(s)$

for example, if you are rusty on Laplace transforms (or their inverse),  you can use [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverseLaplace(Laplace(25-(5-t)%5E2)*(s%2F(s%2Bw))))

2. multiply $H(s)*U(s)$

that will get you a function of s $Y(s)$

3. use the inverse laplace transform to Y(s) to get the $y(t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}(Y(s))$

Answer (score 0):

Luckily in this case there is a symbolic result.

```
OutputResponse[TransferFunctionModel[s/(s + w), s], 25 - (5 - t)^2, t]
res1 = Simplify[%[[1]]]
```

> $-\frac{2 e^{-t w} \left(e^{t w} ((t-5) w-1)+5 w+1\right)}{w^2}$

A procedure to get this (as mentioned) is

```
s/(s + w) LaplaceTransform[25 - (5 - t)^2, t, s]
res2 = InverseLaplaceTransform[%, s, t]
```

> $-\frac{2 e^{-t w} \left(e^{t w} ((t-5) w-1)+5 w+1\right)}{w^2}$

The results for various values of $w$

```
Table[w, {w, 0.1, 1, 0.2}];
Plot[Evaluate@Table[res, {w, %}], {t, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> %]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much...